# Browsing new tags and deleting auto-complete input reverts to tags being sorted by name

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-search, autocomplete

There seems to be a small "bug" (or rather unexpected behaviour) related to the auto-complete when browsing `tags` sorted by `new`.

When inputting text to the auto-complete the behaviour is as expected. However, if you go on and delete all input from the auto-complete, the behaviour I'd expect is that all tags are shown in descending order from newest to oldest. Instead, the view reverts to what is basically the sorting by `name`.

Reproduce this by:

- going to any `tags` section on any SE site (for example https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
- click the `new` tab on the right (for example https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new)
- input text to the auto-complete
- delete that text

Expected behaviour: View of `tags` in newest to oldest sorting

Experienced behaviour: View of `tags` in name sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

There was no logic related to the `new` tab when filtering tags.

When filtering and clearing the filter, new results will come up in the expected order.

This is in the next build.

Comment: That was _quick_! :)

Comment: We aim to please. Our users are important to use. <end of recorded message>.